# A chevron above a consonant, like a tilde

Tags: tilde

I want to put a wedge above a character, like a tilde can place, over an "S" or a "K".

The MWE:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
K_{ij}=\^{K}_{i,(1+j-i)} \qquad \text{para} \qquad i & =1,2,...,\text{NGDL};\\
j & = i,i+1,...,\text{SAB}+i \leq \text{NGDL}\\ 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The K shows without the chevron.
[image: n]

Comment: Do you mean a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron or a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex ? Please post an image of what you search, explain, where you have already searched (saving us from searching there, too) and give an MWE which shows your font setting. Are you willing to use Lua- or XeLaTeX?

Comment: XeLaTeX, please.

Comment: As LaRiFaRi indicates, in math mode you need to use `\hat` for a circumflex accent.

Comment: @AndrewSwann credits go to Mathew. Voted to close as duplicate, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a caron, use `\v{a}` to get ǎ.

For a circumflex, use `\^{a}` to get â.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A caron, \v{a}, and a circumflex, \^{a}.
\end{document}
```

In math mode, try `\hat{a}` for a hat:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
K_{ij}=\hat{K}_{i,(1+j-i)} \qquad \text{para} \qquad i & =1,2,...,\text{NGDL};\\
j & = i,i+1,...,\text{SAB}+i \leq \text{NGDL}\\ 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

For a full list of basic LaTeX accents, see [this WikiBooks page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and thanks a lot for answering and participating here. If you have time, make your example a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) as this is best practise here and makes it easy to reproduce your suggestion.

Comment: I edited my question. I tried with both of them, but I didn't get the results.

Comment: What version of LaTeX are you using? Try using `\hat{a}` for math mode.

Comment: It works with `\hat{}`.

Comment: You also can try `\widehat` (depending on the width of the text – probably `widehat{W}` will look better than `\hat{W}`).

Comment: Now, that Mathew provided a fully working example, there's no reason to maintain the downvote... so unknown downvoter, come on... remove it!